# Use map::empty and map::insert in differents threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, stdmap

Is it safe to use map::empty and map::insert in 2 differents threads without synchronisation?

```
void thread1()
{
        ...
        while(running)
        {
                //get data from network
                ..........

                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                map1.insert(data);
        }
}

 void thread2()
 {
        while(running || !map1.empty())
        {
               std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
               //remove outdated elements from map   
               ......
        }
 }
```

Comment: you are asking if you can remove the `mutex` from that code?

Comment: no, mutex is necessary, i'm asking can I use map1.empty without protection.

Answer (score 5):

No it isn't safe. `std::map` is **not** thread-safe.

Therefore you'll need to use synchronisation techniques such as mutexes. Note that even with mutexes, you still run the risk of invalidating any iterators on other threads when using methods that mutate the map.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the insidious thing about the code from the OP, is that it may well work as he expects - until he comes to do a demo in front of the biggest customer + CEO.

Comment: @MartinBonner: ;-) Which is why I always bring a print out when talking to such folk, and cite designed-in  "security-issues" if something goes awry.

Comment: @MartinBonner what confuses me is that OPs code actually has a `mutex`, but from the code in the question alone it isnt clear what that mutex does nor if the code is meant as example for "with synchronisation" or "without"

Comment: @DanielLangr: Yes, I'd agree with that. I'll delete my first two comments.

Comment: @user463035818 : The OP has a mutex to protect the map when mutating the map - but only attempts to mutate the map if `map1.empty()` returns false.  This saves the performance cost of acquiring the mutex (which is not cheap), when the map *is* empty.  Of course, trading correctness for speed is usually not a good trade-off.

Comment: @MartinBonner uh, now I get it. Thanks for the hints